# Is $a$ or $b \equiv 0 \pmod{5}$ if $a^2-b^2 \equiv 0 \pmod{5}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I have this question, knowing the last in title can i define that at least a or b is divisible by 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, ... no because $a^2 - a^2 \equiv 0$ but neither $a$ need not be equivalent to $0 \mod 5$.

Or for that matter $a^2 - (-a)^2 \equiv 0$ but if $a \ne \equiv 0 \pmod 5$ then $-a\equiv 5-a\not \equiv 0$ either.

You can exhaust all cases.  $0^2 - 0^2, 1^2 - 1^2, 1^2 - 4^2, 2^2 - 2^2, 2^2 - 3^2, 3^2 - 3^2, 3^2 - 2^2, 4^2 - 4^2, 4^2 - 1^2$ are all equiv $0$.

In fact we can see that if $a^2 - b^2 \equiv 0$ then either both are equivalent to zero or *neither* are.

Which makes *perfect* sense becuase if one of them, say $b$, was equivalent to $0$ then $a^2 - b^2 \equiv a^2 - 0^2 \equiv a^2\pmod 5$ (Or if $a\equiv 0$ then $a^2 - b^2 \equiv 0^2 - b^2 \equiv -b^2 \equiv 0\pmod 5$) and there's no reason to assume the other squared (or negative the other squared) would be $0$.

If we think about it is seems really weird that one would think it *would* imply one is equiv to $0$.

Why *DID* you think that?

...

Note also $a^2 - b^2 = (a+b)(a-b)\equiv 0 \pmod 5$.  Because $5$ is prime that means either $5|a+b$ and $a+b \equiv 0 \pmod 5$ or $5|a-b$ and $a-b \equiv 0 \pmod 5$.  Those would mean that if $a^2 - b^2 \equiv 0\pmod 5$ we *MUST* have either $a \equiv b\pmod 5$ or $a \equiv -b \pmod 5$.

That is almost the exact *opposite* of your assumption.

However it's worth noting that $a^2 -b^2 \equiv 0 \pmod n$ wont mean this if $n$ is not prime.

Answer (score 3):

Note that $0 = a^2-b^2 = (a+b)(a-b)$, so either $a-b \equiv 0 \pmod{5}$ or $a+b \equiv 0 \pmod{5}$

---

**UPDATE**

So you are saying $a^2 \pmod{5} = b^2 \pmod{5} = 4$. If $a$ is divisible by $5$, so is $a^2$, so since $a^2 \pmod{5} = 4 \ne 0$, you see that $a$ is not divisible by $5$. Similarly, neither is $b$.

Comment: I still cannot get this. Maybe I explained wrong.

Comment: The original problem is, that a^2 = 4 mod 5 and b^2 = 4 mod 5.

Comment: From there i want to know if is possible define that at least a or b are divisible by 5.

Comment: @RichardKingston That ought to be in your question, but I've answered it separately

Comment: @RichardKingston see update

Comment: Why would $a^2 \equiv 4 \pmod 5$ and $b^2 \equiv 4 \pmod 5$ mean that one of them is $0$?  $0^2 \not \equiv 4$ so you know that *NEITHER* of them can be equiv to $0$.

Comment: If $a^2 \equiv 4\pmod 5$ you can go through all options one after another.  $0^2 \equiv 0 \not \equiv 4$.  $1^2 \equiv 1 \not \equiv 4$.  $2^2 \equiv 4$.  $3^2\equiv 9 \equiv 4$ and $4^2 \equiv 16 \equiv 1\not \equiv 4$.  So the answer is $a=2$ or $3$ and $b=2$ or $3$.  (Note: $3 \equiv -2 \pmod 5$. .. why whoud $a^2 -b^2\equiv 0\pmod5 \implies $ $a$ or $b\equiv 0 \pmod 5$.  In regular arithmetic $a^2 - b^2 = 0$ does *not* mean one or the other is $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Noting your comment to gt6989b's answer, use that

$$a^2-4\equiv 0 \pmod 5 \implies 5|(a-2) \text{ or }5|(a+2)$$
Because $a^2-4=(a-2)(a+2)$.

For both of these, $5|a$ is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Let's supposed that $ a \equiv 0 \pmod{5} $, so $a^{2} \equiv 0 \pmod{5}$, as consequence $b \equiv 0 \pmod{5}$, would also be true, if $a^{2} - b^{2} \equiv 0 \pmod{5}$.

So, if one of the two is multiple of 5, then the other also has to be and if one is not multiple of five, then the other also cannot be.